# filtering nan from numpy array of objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to filter out nan values from an array.
The array is a result of a `unique()` call, on a DataFrame column which contains a mix of strings and NAs.
I cannot find a straightforward way to do it.

```
% sprints = frame['col'].unique()
% sprints
array([nan, 'Sprint 3.3', 'Sprint 2.3', ...], dtype=object)
```

Now I want to filter that `nan`

naturally I am trying:

```
sprints[~np.isnan(sprints)]
```

which gets me an error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

but even if I try to hand-code some alternative way, I bump into the same error:

```
sprints = frame['col'].unique().tolist()
[sprint for sprint in sprints if not np.isnan(sprint)]
...
same error
```

So I am resorting to a brute force approach:

```
def isna(val):
    try:
        return np.isnan(val)
    except:
        return False

sprints = frame['col'].unique().tolist()
[ sprint for sprint in sprints if not isna(sprint)]
```

...and this works, but it feels like there must be a more natural way, right?

There is a `casting` parameter in `numpy.isnan()` but setting it to `'unsafe'` does not fix the problem.

Comment: Doesn't `pandas` have its own `nan` handling methods?  As  you found the `numpy` code is designed to work with float arrays, since `np.nan` is itself a float.  A pandas Series/column with strings is object dtype.  For all practical purposes that's a list, where each element can be a different type.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to first filter the nas on the DataFrame:

```
sprints = frame['col'].dropna().unique().tolist()
```

Thanks to @hpaulj for the hint

Answer (score 0):

For multiple 1d-numpy arrays you can achieve a similar effect to `dropna` with:

```py
import functools
import operator
import numpy as np

def filter_out_nans(*args):
    non_nan_indices = ~functools.reduce(operator.or_, map(np.isnan, args))
    return [arg[non_nan_indices] for arg in args]

x, y, z = filter_out_nans(x, y, z)
```